# #define equivalent in a namespace

Tags: c++, macros, namespaces

I wanted to make an exception class based on std::exception that allows me to give the file, function and line number using built-in macros (at least Visual Studio has them).

Because it's tedious to write these I made a simple #define to do it:

```
#define SOURCE __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__
```

Is there any way I can achieve the same effect without using a macro such that the symbol remains in the Exceptions:: namespace? I don't much like polluting global.

Here's a repo for anyone who's interested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

namespace Exceptions
{
    class ExceptionBase : public std::exception
    {
    public:

        explicit ExceptionBase() : 
            Line(0), File(nullptr), Function(nullptr) {}

        explicit ExceptionBase(std::exception const & exception) : 
            std::exception(exception), Line(0), File(nullptr), Function(nullptr) {}

        explicit ExceptionBase(char const * file, char const * function, unsigned line) :
            File(file), Function(function), Line(line) {}

        explicit ExceptionBase(char const * message, char const * file, char const * function, unsigned line) :
            std::exception(message), File(file), Function(function), Line(line) {}

        ~ExceptionBase() {}

        unsigned Line;
        const char *File, *Function;
    };
}

#define SOURCE __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__

int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        throw Exceptions::ExceptionBase(SOURCE);
    }
    catch(Exceptions::ExceptionBase const & base)
    {
        std::cout << "File: " << base.File << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Function: " << base.Function << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Line: " << base.Line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't. There's a proposal for that, but I'm not sure it's going to make it.

Comment: The reason the answer is "no" is that pre-processor macros are expanded before the compiler even looks at the code.